# Continuity of a complex function $f$ at $a$ implies $\lim \limits_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Assume the complex valued function $f$ of a complex variable is continuous at $a\in\mathbb C$. How can we see that $$\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)=0$$

Comment: It's a consequence of $f$ and $z\mapsto z-a$ both being continuous at $a$.

Comment: Limit arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit of the product is equal to the product of limits. $z-a\to 0$ and $f(z)\to f(a)$ by continuity of $f$ at $a$.